Looking for a numerical algorithm or library to calculate derivatives of degenerate eigenvalues
There is a well known result to easily calculate the derivative of non degenerate eigenvalues :
$$ v_p^T \frac{dA}{dx} v_p = \frac{de_p}{dx} \space\space \space(1)$$
But when they are degenerate, how is it possible to calculate numerically these derivatives ?
To sum up the problem (as far as I can understand). If matrix A is considered,
$$ \boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & x \\x & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
The eigenvalues and the normalized eigenvectors are :
$$ \boldsymbol{\mathsf{\Lambda}} = \begin{pmatrix}1+x & 0 \\0 & 1-x\end{pmatrix} 
,\space\space\space\space
\boldsymbol{\mathsf{V1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$ \mathsf{\frac{\boldsymbol{\mathsf{dA}}}{dx}} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\1 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$
If x=0 (degenerate eigenvalues) 
$$ \boldsymbol{\mathsf{\Lambda}} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
If $\space\boldsymbol{\mathsf{V1}}$ is used in eq. (1), the result is valid. But, if another eigenvectors are used, for example :
$$\boldsymbol{\mathsf{V2}} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
(or any linear combination of them), eq.(1) does not hold.
The purpose of this very simple analytical example is only to illustrate my problem.
Now, I come to my problem : $ \boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}}$ is a large matrix (1000x1000). Eigenvalues and eigenvectors could be numerically calculated with Lapack library. An analytical expression is known for $ \mathsf{\frac{\boldsymbol{\mathsf{dA}}}{dx}} $.
But how can I calculate $ \mathsf{\frac{\boldsymbol{\mathsf{d\Lambda}}}{dx}} $ with the best numerical precision ? Indeed, eigenvalues could be degenerate but, because of numerical precision problem, when are thy considered as degenerate ? And if they are degenerate, how the optimum linear combination of eigenvectors (calculated with Lapack library from $ \boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}}$) could be determined ?
I wonder if there is a library to perform such numerical calculation ? If not, what are the algorithm generally used ?
Thanks for answer.
( n.b. : This question has been asked on math.stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4982283/636388) but someone answered :  Maybe better luck asking here scicomp.stackexchange.com)

You might find some inspiration in degenerate perturbation theory if you like quantum mechanics. There are some worked examples here that might be useful too.

The question would benefit from carefully defining what the various symbols mean. For example, it's unclear to me what $v_p$ and $e_p$ mean in the first question. Second, I was confused because I thought that $V_1, V_2$ are supposed to be eigenvectors, when it's matrices whose columns are eigenvector (or more generally span an eigenspace). All of this just makes it difficult to understand the question.

@DanielShapero. Thanks for your comment. It gave me an idea. See comment, in the answer below.

You should probably write the identity as follows:
$$v_p(x)^T\frac{dA}{dx}(x) v_p(x) = \frac{de_p}{dx}(x),$$
in order to emphasize that $A$, $v_p$, and $e_p$ are functions of $x$. Moreover you need that $A$, $e_p$, and $v_p$ are differentiable functions at $x$. What you are suggesting is to define the eigenvectors as follows:
$$v_1(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1), & x \ne 0, \\ (1,0), & x=0,\end{cases}\quad v_2(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,-1), & x \ne 0, \\ (0,1), & x=0,\end{cases}$$
which makes $v_1, v_2$ discontinuous at $x=0$, and thus also non-differentiable.
The identity does not hold for non-differentiable functions since it is derived as follows:
\begin{align}
Av_p &= e_p v_p \\
\frac{d}{dx}(Av_p) &= \frac{d}{dx}(e_pv_p) \\
\frac{dA}{dx}v_p + A\frac{dv_p}{dx} &= \frac{de_p}{dx}v_p + e_p\frac{dv_p}{dx} \\
v_p^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p + v_p^TA\frac{dv_p}{dx} &= v_p^T\frac{de_p}{dx}v_p + v_p^Te_p\frac{dv_p}{dx} \\
v_p^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p + e_pv_p^T\frac{dv_p}{dx} &= \frac{de_p}{dx}\underbrace{\|v_p\|^2_2}_{1} + e_pv_p^T\frac{dv_p}{dx} \\
v_p^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p &= \frac{de_p}{dx}.
\end{align}
Note that we needed that $v_p$ is differentiable and also that $A$ is symmetric (for $v_p^TA = e_p v_p^T$ and $\|v_p\|_2^2 =1$).
If $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is not symmetric but nevertheless $A$ and $A^T$ are not defective, you can modify the derivation as follows (where $u_p$ is the eigenvector for $A^T$ with eigenvalue $e_p$):
\begin{align}
Av_p &= e_p v_p \\
\frac{d}{dx}(Av_p) &= \frac{d}{dx}(e_pv_p) \\
\frac{dA}{dx}v_p + A\frac{dv_p}{dx} &= \frac{de_p}{dx}v_p + e_p\frac{dv_p}{dx} \\
u_p^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p + u_p^TA\frac{dv_p}{dx} &= u_p^T\frac{de_p}{dx}v_p + u_p^Te_p\frac{dv_p}{dx} \\
u_p^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p + e_pu_p^T\frac{dv_p}{dx} &= \frac{de_p}{dx}(u_p\cdot v_p) + e_pu_p^T\frac{dv_p}{dx} \\
u_p^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p &= \frac{de_p}{dx} (u_p \cdot v_p)
\end{align}
If $A$ is defective I haven't thought about what happens wrt the Jordan decomposition, maybe there is some generalized identity. If you care about singular values and vectors you can also derive an identity. Let $w_p, v_p$ be the left and right singular vectors corresponding to the singular value $\sigma_p$, then:
\begin{align}
Av_p &= \sigma_p w_p \\
\frac{d}{dx}(Av_p) &= \frac{d}{dx}(\sigma_pw_p) \\
\frac{dA}{dx}v_p + A\frac{dv_p}{dx} &= \frac{d\sigma_p}{dx}w_p + \sigma_p\frac{dw_p}{dx} \\
w_p^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p + w_p^TA\frac{dv_p}{dx} &= w_p^T\frac{d\sigma_p}{dx}w_p + w_p^T\sigma_p\frac{dw_p}{dx} \\
w_p^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p +\sigma_p v_p^T\frac{dv_p}{dx} &= \frac{d\sigma_p}{dx}\underbrace{\|w_p\|^2_2}_{1}+ \sigma_pw_p^T\frac{dw_p}{dx} \\
w_p^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p + \sigma_p \frac{d}{dx}(\underbrace{\|v_p\|^2_2}_{1})&= \frac{d\sigma_p}{dx} + \sigma_p \frac{d}{dx}(\underbrace{\|w_p\|^2_2}_{1}) \\
w_p^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p &= \frac{d\sigma_p}{dx}
\end{align}
Edit:
Based on the arxiv paper one can study instead:
\begin{align}
Av_p &= e_p v_p \\
\frac{d}{dx}(Av_p) &= \frac{d}{dx}(e_pv_p) \\
\frac{dA}{dx}v_p + A\frac{dv_p}{dx} &= \frac{de_p}{dx}v_p + e_p\frac{dv_p}{dx} \\
v_q^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p + v_q^TA\frac{dv_p}{dx} &= v_q^T\frac{de_p}{dx}v_p + v_q^Te_p\frac{dv_p}{dx} \\
v_q^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p + e_qv_q^T\frac{dv_p}{dx} &= \frac{de_p}{dx}\underbrace{v_q^Tv_p}_{\delta_{qp}} + e_pv_q^T\frac{dv_p}{dx} \\
v_q^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_p &=\frac{de_p}{dx}\delta_{pq} + (e_p-e_q)v_q^T\frac{dv_p}{dx}
\end{align}
The last is the equivalent to equation (3) in the arxiv paper. Consider your toy example:
$$\frac{dA}{dx} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
Then the equations are:
\begin{align}
v_1^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_1 &= \frac{de_1}{dx} \\
v_1^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_2 &= (e_2-e_1)v_1^T\frac{dv_2}{dx} \\
v_2^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_1 &= (e_1-e_2)v_2^T\frac{dv_1}{dx} \\
v_2^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_2 &= \frac{de_2}{dx}
\end{align}
If $e_1(0) = e_2(0)$ then the second and third equation reduce to:
$$v_1^T\frac{dA}{dx}v_2 = 0,$$
and moreover you know that $v_1^Tv_2 = 0$ and $\|v_1\|_2^2 = \|v_2\|^2_2$, thus (the upper indices in the following stand for the components of the vectors):
\begin{align}
v_1^1 v_2^2 + v_1^2 v_2^1 &= 0 \\
v_1^1 v_2^1 + v_1^2 v_2^2 &= 0 \\
v_1^1 v_1^1 + v_1^2 v_1^2 &= 1 \\
v_2^1 v_2^1 + v_2^2 v_2^2 &= 1.
\end{align}
So you have four coupled equations for the components, and I suppose you should be able to get those up to sign and order from the above. I am not sure how you would fix the order and signs from the above though. But that is ambiguous even in the case without repeating eigenvalues as far as I can tell, so one has to be careful in order to enforce continuity.

I know that the identity does not hold for non differenciable function. And this my problem, if x=0, the eigenvectors I suggested is only an example. Any linear combination is also a solution.

@Stef1611 If you know that the identity doesn't hold for non-differentiable functions then you know why you cannot use this formula with your $\boldsymbol{V}_2$. Defining $\boldsymbol{V}(0) = \boldsymbol{V}_2$ makes $\boldsymbol{V}$ a non-differentiable function. Defining $\boldsymbol{V}(x) = \boldsymbol{V}_1$ makes it differentiable and everything works just fine. The point is that you cannot use the formula to compute what you want if you violate its assumptions.

This only a simple analytical example to explain my numerical problem. When A matrix is diagonalized with Lapack subroutines (for example), if some eigenvalues are degenerate, the associated eigenvectors will not be the eigenvectors that assure continuity. But, the right combination of them is needed. How could I find it ?

@Stef1611 I don't think you can recover that information in your toy example just from data at $x=0$. You explicitly need data at other $x$ values to recover things.

In the question, Daniel Shapero gave me a good idea. The problem is well known in quantum mechanics with the Feynman- Helmann Theorem. See these links for example : https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.66.033110 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.04876. I will try to find the linear combination of eigenvectors that diagonalizes the submatrix (ie where there is degeneracy) $d\Lambda/dx$. It is just an another eigenvalues problem. But I am afraid of reinventing the wheel.

@Stef1611 I applied the idea from the arxiv paper to your toy example above. It seems to work up to some details. I have no idea what numerical method would work for solving the system involving quadratic mixes of the components of the eigenvectors though.
